# override python arguments when packaging for debian

Tags: python, debian, package

I am trying to build a debian package of a python module.

I have to pass some arguments to setup.py and to remove the --force option that is passed by default.

I launch the build process by calling

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

To override the calls to python, I tried to add in debian/rules:

```
override_dh_python2:
    dh_python2 --lapack-home=/usr
```

But it doesn't change anything, my flag is not passed when compiling.
What should I do to override python in the packaging process?

Bests